# FFmpeg will not run from php

Tags: php, windows, iis-7, ffmpeg, exec

This is a live server i am on a Windows 2008 Web Edition R2 server with IIS7.

I have tried all of this locally and it works perfectly. At first i thought this may have been a permisson issue i gave all ffmpeg folders and output folders full control. I also checked the php ini file to make sure `exec` is enabled.

I was intially running the `exec()` function i later changed it to the `system()` function to see what ffmpeg was outputting. With the `system()` function it returns the error "Acess is denied". All of my research points to a IIS setting or Application Pool not having the correct permission. Any help would be much appreciated.

FFmpeg location: C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe

I have been working on this for nearly a week even my server provider has no answer on why ffmpeg will not run from php. I believe this is a little deeper than full paths. It's obviously a permission problem but the question is where is the permission problem?

It also seems that no `.exe` file can be executed from php.

```
system ("$ffmpeg -i yourvideo/.mp4 -threads 1 -ss 20 -b 10k  -s 240x180 -vf fps=fps=1/20 -vframes 12 -aspect 4:3 thumbs/yourvideo/yourvideo.%01d.jpg 2>&1");
```

Comment: I gave full permission to the C drive and now it gives ffmpeg "Permisson is Denied" instead of "Acess Is Denied"

Answer (score 0):

Just use full path of ffmpeg and all problem should be gone.Common problem of liver server

Comment: try to print the command and run locally, weather it is correct

Comment: print same command and run using server in putty or whatever without code.Weather this generate output file

Comment: This definetly a permission problem i have ran this in the command line hundreds of times.

Comment: try to login in putty with iis server name and then try

Comment: make sure you testing same command in putty over server not local, then you can sure about permission